# Cannot start container: process is killed

Tags: docker, kubernetes

my containers are killed on a new installation of Fedora 24 atomic:

```
#docker run -ti nginx /bin/bash

docker: Error response from daemon: Cannot start container f24104b29f7f1f1614024414e8346e1a98c722c027f4122e6c70f7ace0cc5353: [9] System error: exit status 1.
```

After some debugging session, I think the process gets killed right after trying to assign an address on network bridge (see docker daemon logs in the next links). But I have no idea why is that nor how to debug further.

Some additional info is reported here:

- SELinux is disabled:

  - bash-4.3# getenforce -> Permissive
- docker [info](https://gist.github.com/mrceresa/f7cb3bc42958f5446b7baf2aa0246df5#file-gistfile1-txt)
- docker daemon log in [debug](https://gist.github.com/mrceresa/895efaefe14c89298ee75a56ad8bb6e7#file-docker-d) mode. At line 9 it receives the KILL signal.

Any help would really be appreciated!

Best,

Mario

Comment: can you disable selinux with `setenforce 0` and then try again?

Comment: Thanks Federkun! I've already disabled it: '-bash-4.3# getenforce 
Permissive'

Answer (score 2):

I've just found the problem:
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1320601

Adding the systemd flag to the launch script of the daemon:
--exec-opt native.cgroupdriver=systemd

solved the problem.

Thanks, Federkun, for help!

Best,

Mario